# Where is the python ssl.CERT_REQUIRED defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, cpython

Where is the python ssl.CERT_REQUIRED defined?

I searched in the ssl.py, (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/00464bbed66e5f64bdad7f930b315a88d5afccae/Lib/ssl.py), it seems there is only usage, no declaration found, how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's defined in `sslmodule_init_constants(PyObject*)` of [`Modules/_ssl.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/79ccc03b62d819d83e592c6c8038545d9263a0d4/Modules/_ssl.c#L5739):

```c
    PyModule_AddIntConstant(m, "CERT_REQUIRED",
                            PY_SSL_CERT_REQUIRED);
```

where `PY_SSL_CERT_REQUIRED` is defined in the enum

```c
enum py_ssl_cert_requirements {
    PY_SSL_CERT_NONE,
    PY_SSL_CERT_OPTIONAL,
    PY_SSL_CERT_REQUIRED
};
```